# Python, refrencing class variables with self in method declaration

Tags: python, oop, self

I'm trying to reference a variable tha I declared in **init** as a default value for one of my class methods but i get the NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.c = f

    def b(self, d=self.c):
        pass
```

how can I do this then?

this is parts of my code

```py
class World:
    def __init__(self, shp):
        self.shape = shp
    def position_finder(self, pos0=(int(self.shape[0]/2), int(self.shape[1]/2)), t_rang=int(self.shape[0]/2), f_rang=0):
        pass

world_shape = (100, 100)

world = World(world_shape)
world.position_finder()
```

Comment: Let me return the question: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I inserted parts of my code into the problem, it may answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is default to `None` because it is set at definition time. Then, when the instance method is called you can detect this and if still `None` set your default. Like this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.c = f

    def b(self, d=None):
        if d is None:
            d = self.c
        return d


a = A(3)
print(a.b())
```

which prints `3`.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I thought there would be a cleaner way of doing it and I dont know it. tnx.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the idiomatic way to do this, and it doesn't conflate class values with instance values. You can't reference values that don't exist yet (instance values) while defining the class.

Comment: yeah. makes sense, the instance can't exist in class.

Answer (score -2):

`b()` doesn't know what's going on inside `__init__()`. So if you want to use a variable across multiple **methods**, declare it as a **property** inside the class.

```py
class A:
    c = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 0  # this line is unnecessary now

    def b(self, d=c):  # "self." is not needed, when defining the arguments
        pass

    # if you use a variable in a function, you must use the self.variable
    def test(self):
        print(self.c)
```

Comment: what if the value I want to assign to c is passed in class instantiation, like how I edited the problem.